# How to disable my family settings?

Tags: parental-control

I don't want to use my family feature.

Where in my phone setting can I disable or remove it?

I have try disabling it so many times but it is not working

Comment: It is almost impossible. You could ask your parents to turn it off but if they don't want that there is no solution for this. Microsoft has extremely blocked this on Windows (Phone) 8(.1)

Answer (score 2):

Solution for this issue is that, you could ask your parents to remove your from the list.
One by one steps are given below,

1. From a web browser, go to http://account.microsoft.com/family and sign in with the Microsoft account of an adult in the family.
2. To remove a child, choose Remove at the top of the section labeled Select a child to view or edit their settings.
3. To remove an adult, including the account you used to sign in with, choose Remove at the top of the Adults section. If you're the only adult in the family, you'll need to remove all the kids before you can remove yourself.
4. Select the person you want to remove from the family.
5. Select the Remove button that appears when you've chosen the person to remove.